# Heter Bamos - When?

Tags: halacha, history, korban

When did the heter bamos (the time when it was permitted for klal yisrael to build their own bamos) begin and end?

Answer (score 11):

[Mishnah Zevachim 14:4-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zevachim.14.4?lang=bi) describe the times that *bamot* were permitted and forbidden:

1. Before the *mishkan* was set up - *bamot* permitted
2. Once the *mishkan* was set up in the desert - *bamot* forbidden
3. While the *mishkan* was in Gilgal - *bamot* permitted
4. While the *mishkan* was in Shiloh - *bamot* forbidden
5. While the *mishkan* was in Nov and Giv'on - *bamot* permitted
6. Once the *beit hamikdash* was built in Yerushalayim and from then on - *bamot* forbidden.